# Bivariate probability distribution(s) over unit square, uniform marginals, midpoint is saddlepoint

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, optimization, uniform-distribution, bivariate-distributions

Construct a bivariate probability distribution--or family of such distributions--over the unit square (corners $(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)$)
with uniform marginals and having a saddlepoint at $(1/2,1/2)$. Perhaps without loss of generality, let the line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ have its maximum at $(1/2,1/2)$, and the line from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ have its minimum at $(1/2,1/2).$
Of course, the uniform distribution over the square could be regarded as, in some sense, fulfilling the conditions, but I am interested in constructions of a less trivial nature.

Answer (score 1):

Does $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = 2x+2y-4xy$ fit the bill?

Comment: I mean, it is an answer, but I don't know whether the answer satisfies his or her unstated criteria for "less trivial."

Comment: Yes, that's great! Further, can one embed this in a larger class of examples? I have a series of estimates of such bivariate probability distributions under different (quantum-information-theoretic) scenarios that I want to explain--and anticipate that they have some elegant form (possibly the  one advanced--but maybe some others). I had done some investigating using the Mathematica "CopulaDistribution" command, but hadn't managed to find anything yet of an appealing nature. So, I'd like, if possible, some broad characterization of these types of distributions.

Comment: Yes, that's great! Further, can one embed this in a larger class of examples? I have a one-parameter family of estimates of such bivariate probability distributions under different (quantum-information-theoretic) scenarios that I want to explain--and anticipate that they have some elegant form (possibly the  one advanced--but maybe some others). I had done some investigating using the Mathematica "CopulaDistribution" command, but hadn't managed to find anything yet of an appealing nature. So, I'd like, if possible, some broad characterization of these types of distributions.